# javascript onclick button won't work on single click

Tags: javascript, onclick

I can't get a javascript to call a function on one click. I would have to click the button several times in order for it to execute. here is what I have tried so far:

```
<a href="javascript:delete_todo(4);void(0)"><img border="0" align="absmiddle" src="b_x.gif"></a>

<a href="javascript:delete_todo(4)"><img border="0" align="absmiddle" src="b_x.gif"></a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:delete_todo(4)"><img border="0" align="absmiddle" src="b_x.gif"></a>

<a onclick="javascript:delete_todo(4)"><img border="0" align="absmiddle" src="b_x.gif"></a>
```

The code is added by another javascript function that adds the line of code to a table td using .innerHTML

Has anyone had this problem and found a solution?

Comment: when using the "onclick" attribute, you shouldn't need to specify javascript:  you should be able to do onclick="delete_todo(4)".  Also either don't include the href attribute for the link, or link it to "#" rather than including a javascript void call in there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers should always be in the onclick. Using `javascript:` is bad form.

```
<a href="#" onclick="delete_todo(4);return false;">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Try to remove `javascript:` in `onClick` atribute.
Here is working example in jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ep7R9/